# Chrome Extension Content Security Policy not Allowing Resources

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I receive the following errors when loading a local chrome extension:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://widget.intercom.io/widget/APPID' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' http://localhost https://widget.intercome.io/ 'unsafe-eval'".

index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://bbmhkchajfbhfjkfiaadlnohbfhbnegj' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I attempted to put the following line in my `manifest.json`:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://localhost https://widget.intercome.io/ 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

Shouldn't this last line in particular allow me access to these two resources?

Comment: maybe this is related : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12129214/2558252

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea with the `https://widget.intercome.io` CSP rule, but you may need to

1. correct the spelling of your domain name (your error has `intercom.io`, but your CSP says `intercome.io`)
2. remove the trailing slash (I'm not sure, but none of the CSP examples I've found use a trailing slash)
3. reload your extension after making changes

The `localhost` error is caused by enforcement of the same-origin policy, not the CSP. (Ajax requests, which are governed by the `connect-src` CSP directive, are not restricted by Chrome extensions' default CSP.) You need to add `http://localhost/*` as a [host permission in your manifest's `permissions` field](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr):

```
"permissions": [
    "http://localhost/*",
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [apsillers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29969569/1677912), for anyone that comes here in the future:

This is correct, but make sure you include it in a separate file. I was running into an inline issue, so I just created a file called `intercom.js` and then included the script there and in my HTML I include it `<script src="intercom.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Also this is what worked for me:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://localhost https://widget.intercom.io https://js.intercomcdn.com 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```