# Outputting Google API Calls Inside Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

My aim is to output some of my Google Analytics data inside a new-tab page using a Chrome extension.

I've followed the "Hello Analytics API: JavaScript quickstart for web applications" found at 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js#clientId as the basis for my new-tab page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello Analytics - A quickstart guide for JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>

<button id="auth-button" hidden>Authorize</button>

<h1>Hello Analytics</h1>

<textarea cols="80" rows="20" id="query-output"></textarea>

<script>

  // Replace with your client ID from the developer console.
  var CLIENT_ID = 'TAKEN OUT FOR SECURITY';

  // Set authorized scope.
  var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'];


  function authorize(event) {
    // Handles the authorization flow.
    // `immediate` should be false when invoked from the button click.
    var useImmdiate = event ? false : true;
    var authData = {
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: SCOPES,
      immediate: useImmdiate
    };

    gapi.auth.authorize(authData, function(response) {
      var authButton = document.getElementById('auth-button');
      if (response.error) {
        authButton.hidden = false;
      }
      else {
        authButton.hidden = true;
        queryAccounts();
      }
    });
  }


function queryAccounts() {
  // Load the Google Analytics client library.
  gapi.client.load('analytics', 'v3').then(function() {

    // Get a list of all Google Analytics accounts for this user
    gapi.client.analytics.management.accounts.list().then(handleAccounts);
  });
}


function handleAccounts(response) {
  // Handles the response from the accounts list method.
  if (response.result.items && response.result.items.length) {
    // Get the first Google Analytics account.
    var firstAccountId = response.result.items[0].id;

    // Query for properties.
    queryProperties(firstAccountId);
  } else {
    console.log('No accounts found for this user.');
  }
}


function queryProperties(accountId) {
  // Get a list of all the properties for the account.
  gapi.client.analytics.management.webproperties.list(
      {'accountId': accountId})
    .then(handleProperties)
    .then(null, function(err) {
      // Log any errors.
      console.log(err);
  });
}


function handleProperties(response) {
  // Handles the response from the webproperties list method.
  if (response.result.items && response.result.items.length) {

    // Get the first Google Analytics account
    var firstAccountId = response.result.items[0].accountId;

    // Get the first property ID
    var firstPropertyId = response.result.items[0].id;

    // Query for Views (Profiles).
    queryProfiles(firstAccountId, firstPropertyId);
  } else {
    console.log('No properties found for this user.');
  }
}


function queryProfiles(accountId, propertyId) {
  // Get a list of all Views (Profiles) for the first property
  // of the first Account.
  gapi.client.analytics.management.profiles.list({
      'accountId': accountId,
      'webPropertyId': propertyId
  })
  .then(handleProfiles)
  .then(null, function(err) {
      // Log any errors.
      console.log(err);
  });
}


function handleProfiles(response) {
  // Handles the response from the profiles list method.
  if (response.result.items && response.result.items.length) {
    // Get the first View (Profile) ID.
    var firstProfileId = response.result.items[0].id;

    // Query the Core Reporting API.
    queryCoreReportingApi(firstProfileId);
  } else {
    console.log('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
  }
}


function queryCoreReportingApi(profileId) {
  // Query the Core Reporting API for the number sessions for
  // the past seven days.
  gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
    'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
    'start-date': '7daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'today',
    'metrics': 'ga:sessions'
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
    document.getElementById('query-output').value = formattedJson;
  })
  .then(null, function(err) {
      // Log any errors.
      console.log(err);
  });
}

  // Add an event listener to the 'auth-button'.
  document.getElementById('auth-button').addEventListener('click', authorize);
</script>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=authorize"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I get the following errors:

- Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
  Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob:
  filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline'
  keyword, a hash
  ('sha256-ZJ1hGXIQLHmnXhFZqYWEDfv/ypJQ/Yvh6mYGne3Nf0s='), or a nonce
  ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
- Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=authorize' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".

Please advise.

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129077/content-security-policy-cannot-load-google-api-in-chrome-extension) + [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy)

Comment: Thank you for those resources. This question proved to be helpful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681803/loading-google-api-javascript-client-library-into-chrome-extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, [inline script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution)(Your first error) won't be executed, and only [local script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#resourceLoading) is loaded (Your second error).

To solve this, take a look at [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy), the recommendation would be extracting inline script to an external script (Your first error) and making a local copy of remote script (Your second error).